# SAS - input list of tables as macro parameter

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I would like to input a list of tables as a macro parameter.

Macro Code:

```
%MACRO Marco_Name ( Table_Name ) ;
    PROC SQL;    
    execute (
    select (owner ||'.'||table_name) as table_name from dba_tables 
    where table_name in (&Table_Name.)
   )
   QUIT;
%MEND Marco_Name ;
```

When I would invoke the macro with e.g.:

```
%Marco_Name ( Table_Name = 'table1', 'table2, 'table3')
```

I would like to the code to resolve to:

```
select (owner ||'.'||table_name) as table_name from dba_tables
where table_name in ('table1', 'table2, 'table3')
```

Comment: Don't include the commas. The SAS `IN ()` operator doesn't need them. If you are really using pass thru code that does need them then have the macro add them. `%let table_namec=%sysfunc(tranwrd(&table_name,%str( ),%str(,)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of marco programming.

The `%STR` macro function is used to wrap values containing commas that would otherwise confound the macro processor when passed as parameters.

Invoke the macro as follows:

```
%MyMacro ( Table_Name = %str ( 'table1', 'table2, 'table3' ) )
```